# Why Log4j2 Doesn't Log Before System.exit(1)

Tags: java, logging, log4j, system

When I use System.exit(1) after logging an error via Log4j2, the system close but the log doesn't be written at log files. In normal situations without using System.exit(1) logging works fine and logs everything. Only when I use System.exit(1) after a log, the log doesn't be written to log files. Why is that?

This code works fine and logs:

```
loggerUtil.error("something went wrong");
```

This code doesn't log:

```
loggerUtil.error("something went wrong");
System.exit(1);
```

I found that the system exits before waits ending logging operations. What should I do or what is the solution? Is there anything like System.waitAndExit()?

Comment: Can you add your Log4j2 configuration? In particular, are you using async loggers? Are you running in a servlet environment?

Answer (score 1):

Below code did the trick for me:

```
   Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           LogManager.shutdown();
       }        
   });
```

Comment: There is no need to add the shutdown hook programmatically, just set `log4j2.enableShutdownHook` to `true` (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#shutdownHookEnabled)). The default value is `true`, unless running in a servlet environment (i.e. the classpath contains `javax.servlet.*` classes).